# Auto complete feature using angularjs and sql server database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-server, autocomplete

I have an sql database table which contains the following columns.

```
Row1  Row2 Row3 Id Country
1      1a   1b  34  europe
2      2a   2b  45  US
3      3a   4d  5g  Australia
```

I am implementing a aut complete feature in the front end using angularjs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview
This is the plunker which shows an example of autocomplete.

When user types anything in the input field, it should auto complete and show various options. The list of items which it should refer to is the Row1, Row2 and Row3.

so, if user types 1 in the input field, it should show 1a and 1b as the values for auto complete.

The backend is c#. I can get the database column values of Row1, Row2 and Row3 to front end. thats not an issue.

Can someone tell me how to implement this feature at the UI side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below link for angularjs in c#. It will help you definatly.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-auto-complete-textbox-using-angularjs-in-mvc5/

Comment: Hi, Is there any other autocomplete example. i am not able to open the .rar file.

Comment: Download zip file from this link ..  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2F_y5DLKS7leHRjbEZNaHhaZkE/view?invite=CLiJ-7sG&ts=577d0675&pref=2&pli=1